# Match filenames in a folder with a list of filenames in R

Tags: r

I have a list of filenames in text format, meaning just the filenames and not the physical files in a folder. FOR example....

```
   ECGVW103899_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr
   ECGVW104077_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr
   ECGVW104081_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr
   ECGVW104121_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr
   ECGVW104182_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr
   .
   .
   .
```

I have a folder with a list of files. These files include the names in the list that I indicated above(and some additional files). I need to separate the additional files in the folder by moving it to a separate folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seeing which files are not in your list is straightforward using indexing. As for moving the files, see [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/21889-Move-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-R)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may give you the result you're looking for.

```
files.to.keep <- c("ECGVW103899_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr",
                   "ECGVW104077_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr",
                   "ECGVW104081_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr",
                   "ECGVW104121_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr",
                   "ECGVW104182_wholecaseRRiQTi.rr")

source.path <- # Path to file source folder
destination.path <- # Path to file destination folder

# Create destination folder if it does not exist
ifelse(!dir.exists(destination.path), dir.create(destination.path), FALSE)

# Get list of files in source folder
filenames <- list.files(source.path)

# Move files that are not in files.to.keep to the destination folder
lapply(filenames, function(x) 
                    if(!(x %in% files.to.keep))
                      {file.rename(from = file.path(source.path,x),to = file.path(destination.path,x))})
```

Comment: I have created an empty destination folder to move the additional files that do not match. What is the purpose of the ifelse line in that case?

Comment: Also the code does not move the files to the destination folder. But it gives me an output like [[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

Comment: That's there just as a check in order to prevent errors. It makes it so that it will create the destination folder automatically if it does not already exist to prevent the code from breaking.

Comment: the code doesn't move the files to the destination folder but rather gives an output[[1]] [1] FALSE